# How to display popupMenu after clicking a link in html file for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-webview

I have created an application that requires the popupMenu to be displayed when a particular link is clicked in the html file.

Now I am not sure how I can get the click event for the link to open the popupMenu. Can anyone please advise? Am I going at this the right way?

Comment: Yes I have opened the html file using webview, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Craete a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for your [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).
Now each time the user clicks a link, the function [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) is called and the link pressed is passed as a String parameter. In this way, you can catch when your user clicked the link by checking this url parameter (second param of the function).

Finally, when you catch that the link is pressed, you show the popup.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             //if the url is your popup url
             //show the popup
             //if you want the web view to load the url return false; else return true;             
             //by default return false btw!

       }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif but I need some more explanation please, how can I connect the link clicked from the webView? Can you provide me with a small example please? for reference?

Comment: Thank you Sherif, I will implement this immediately, much thanks

Comment: Sherif small question, how can I catch the pressed link? suppose I have 30 links on a view and user clicks the 10th link, how can I catch that event? Appreciate the help.

Comment: oh you should know the `href` of the link. so u catch by : `if(url.equals("kaza kaza"))` ...